# Hi Guys! Can we give cartesian coordinates as input using MoveIt KDL or any package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We designed 4 Dof robotic arm using solid works.We converted Solid works file into urdf file using sw2urdf exporter.Later we created moveit package.
Now we will get target interms of Cartesian  coordinates, the end effector should reach the target position. Can we able to do that using KDL or any other packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256852/hi-guys!-can-we-give-cartesian-coordinates-as-input-using-moveit-kdl-or-any-package?/) by [SaiKumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29668/saikumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand you correctly, you want to plan towards *Pose* goals. I would suggest you work through the [Moveit! tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/) to learn how to use it. Other options are available as well but I think MoveIt! is probably a good place to get started.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0